# xp_cmdshell dir different results when passing command as variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dos, dir, xp-cmdshell

I am creating a stored procedure to track some server's folders' used space using SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have run into an interesting issue for a particular directory.

When I run `EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir "\\servername\e$\media\Google" /s /-C'` I get a result:

[image]

However, when I use a variable for the dos command
`DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(255) = 'dir "\\servername\e$\media\Google" /s /-C'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @dir`

I get a different result:

[image]

You can see that the number of files is the same, but the number of bytes used is different.  Here are the details for the subdirectory with the files:

Not using variable:

[image]

Using @dir variable:

[image]

You can see that although it seems to have each of the files the same size, the total is different.

I have other subdirectories with zip files that do not exhibit this behavior.
Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause this?  Or how to fix?

Comment: I have no idea why this happens, but I did reproduce a discrepancy on both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012. (Oddly, I see a discrepancy only in the “Dir(s)...bytes free” line not the “File(s)...bytes” line.) I tried a few commands other than DIR and couldn’t find any that produced different results when executed with a string and with a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not the answer you're looking for but I hope it helps you in some way :)

I notice in the first comparison:

181661290 - 181644906 = 16384 / 2048 = 8

So I thought maybe, for some reason, when you use the variable the command count the "cluster size" (I guess 2048 bytes) of the sub-folders...

But then I notice:

8131596 - 8119308 = 12288 / 2048 = 6

So only 6 folders are adding the 2048 bytes in there, and I don't know why.

Then you said:

> Interesting, so when I run with just *.zip, the two results match each other.

Maybe adding the switch /a-d (to not show the folders) to your command line solves the problem.

I'm adding [this post of sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost541345.aspx) I found maybe it has something to do with the problem:

> CompressedBit    AS CASE WHEN Attributes&2048=2048 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,

Comment: So when I add the /a-d switch, the results are consistent, but the bytes used matches the size, not the Size on disk.  That should be good enough for my space tracking, but I'm still wondering what caused the issue that adding that switch fixed it???

Comment: For me it's difficult to try to figure it out. First of all I need to know why only the 6 folders showed in the second pair of pictures add the 2048... Then we should know if the 2048 are some kind of data stored in the folder itself or some data xp_cmdshell command is taking from somewhere else.
If I manage to configure an environment to test it I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

Bytes free will always be different if people are adding, editing or deleting files on the share.

I tried running this on my test machine and had the same results for both executions.  I am using Windows 7 with 2014 CTP.

Are you sure there are not hidden or system files that changing the totals?  Directories, indexes, etc also take up space but do not show up.  You are not specifying a wild card pattern for file matching.

Here is a layman's article on the topic.

http://ask-leo.com/why_does_the_space_used_by_files_on_my_hard_drive_show_different_numbers_depending_on_how_i_look.html

If you manually select the files from Windows Explorer, do you get the same total?

Try just specifying 'dir *.zip /s'.  This will only select the zip files.  Please write back with the results!

Comment: The issue was definitely not due to people working on files in the directory - I was able to get the same results consistently.  I also included options to grab hidden and system files.  The screenshots above where a variable is NOT being used for the dir command matches what is shown in Windows Explorer.  I will take a look at the other two items you brought up.

Comment: Did you try running the command with '*.zip' to look at just those files.  That should toss out the rest of the junk.

Comment: I haven't had a chance, but I will today - however, you can see that all the files in that subdirectory are zip files, so I'm thinking the results will be the same.

Comment: Interesting, so when I run with just *.zip, the two results match each other.  The only difference I notice in the results that don't match versus the ones that do is the ones that don't match have entries with the <DIR> in them (such as row 25 in my screenshots above).

Comment: That is what I told you and it is the answer to your question.  There are hidden indexes, files, directories that might be changing between runs.  You are picking it all up with a 'dir \\server\directory /s' command.  If you do a 'dir \\server\directory\*.zip /s' it only picks up files with an zip extension.  Thus, this is hidden feature or side effect of the operating system.  SQL Server is working fine.  -J

Comment: That doesn't explain it at all.  I am consistently getting the same results when I run the command with a variable.  I am consistently getting different results when I run the command hardtyped.  This is NOT due to stuff being worked on or changing.

Comment: Which hard typed command??  I bet you a star bucks coffee, run 'dir \\server\directory\*.zip /s' over and over again.  Same results.  But not specifying a file brings everything in.  So what is your theory on what is changing??  Hidden and System Files; Directories; The File Allocation Table or Master File Table; The Log File to name a few.

Comment: If I run `EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir "\\servername\e$\media\Google" /s /-C'` ten times, I'm going to get the same file size every time - 181644906 bytes.  If I run `DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(255) = 'dir "\\servername\e$\media\Google" /s /-C'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @dir` ten times, I'm going to get the same file size every time - 181661290 bytes.  So how is changing "other" files causing that???

Comment: The two ways your provided to call xp_cmdshell should give the same result.  They do on my machine!!  Are you executing the code the same way?  Same account?  It will execute under the account that SQL Server is running under from SSMS.  Hopefully a domain account.  Log into the SQL Server using the domain account, at a command prompt, run the 'dir' command.  Add the /A command to list all files.  If a job, then it runs under the SQL Agent account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56443/discussion-between-crafty-dba-and-dave-gugg).